# Proving $X(f)=X(g)$, where $X\in T_p(M)$ and $f(x) =g(x)$ for all $x\in U\subseteq M $

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

This question is from my assignment on smooth manifolds and I need help in proving this result.

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $p\in M$. Let $f,g \in C^{\infty} (M)$ and $U \subset M$ be an open subset such that $p\in U$ and $f(x)=g(x)$  for all $x\in U$. Show that for any $X\in T_p(M)$, we have $X(f)=X(g)$.

So, I think that it is clear that how  $X(f) =X(g)$  on $U$  ( as it is given  that $f(x)=g(x)$ are equal on $U$ ) but how to approach this when a point  say $x\in M \setminus U$. I am at loss of ideas.

Kindly shed some light on this.

Comment: $X(f)$ and $X(g)$ are real numbers, and "on $U$" or "at a point $x \in M \setminus U$" do not mean anything.

Comment: @Plop $X(f)$ and $X(g)$ are actually functions

Comment: No, no, since $X$ is only a tangent vector. If $X$ is a vector field, then $X(f)$ is the image of the function $f$ under the derivation along $X$. But here, $X(f)$ is just the derivative of $f$ in the direction of $X$.

Comment: What is your definition of $T_pM$?

Comment: Me or the OP? For me, $T_p M$ denotes the tangent space of $M$ at point $p$, and it is isomorphic to the space of "point derivations" (I don't know the word in english) at $p$, i.e. the space of linear forms $\alpha$ on $C^\infty(M)$ satisfying the Leibniz rule at $p$, that is, $\forall f,g\quad \alpha(fg) = \alpha(f)g(p) + f(p)\alpha(g)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T_pM$ denotes the tangent space of $M$ at point $p$ that is the set of all derivations $X: C^{\infty}(M) \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ ($X$ is a linear map) satisfying the Leibniz rule at $p$, that is, $\forall f,g \in C^{\infty}(M)$
$$X(fg)=f(p)Xg+g(p)Xf,$$
then, to prove that $Xf=Xg$ if $f$ and $g$ agree, setting $h=f-g$, by linearity is suffices to show that $Xh=0$ whenever $h$ vanishes in a neighborhood $W$ of $p.$

Let $A$ be a closed subset $M \setminus W$. Then exists a smooth function $u \in C^{\infty}(M)$ equal to $1$ on $A$ and is supported in $M \setminus \{p\}$. Because $u=1$ where $h$ is nonzero, $hu=h$. Since $h(p) = f(p)-g(p) = 0 = u(p) $, by Leibniz rule
$$Xh = X(hu) =h(p)Xu+u(p)Xh =0 $$

Comment: How you are sure that such a smooth function u must exist in last paragraph of your answer?

Comment: it is possible to build such a function, I suggest you make a sketch to convince yourself, put it constant equal to $1$ in $A$ and with smooth decay outside $A$, decaying to zero in $p$.

Comment: I got it u(p)=0, but how did you wrote that h(p)=0?

Comment: $h$ vanishes in a neighborhood $W$ of $p$, see your hypothesis,$ f=g$ in a neighborhood.